# What does this keyboard shortcut symbol indicate?

Tags: keyboard

The following was taken out of Photoshop. But I have seen many applications showing the symbol on the left as part of a keyboard combination. Which key is it?

[image]

<kbd>[Something]</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Something is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the alt/**option** key.

Think of it as a **switch** in circuit diagrams.

[image]